# Task Scheduler Event when an Application Ended

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

How can I make a Task in the Windows 7 Task Scheduler with Trigger when an Application Ends ?

I want to make a task when my "explorer.exe" process ends.
How can i make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an in-built trigger for this. If the application in question creates its own [custom task category](https://superuser.com/a/562570/138343) and logs events such as app closure then of course you can make use of that, but otherwise I don't think Task Scheduler can help you with this.

A workaround would be to schedule a batch file/script to periodically check which tasks are running (using the `tasklist` command or similar) and react accordingly.

A program like [Shutter](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=shutter) can also be useful:

> Shutter is a multifunctional scheduling utility, which has a user friendly and easy-to-use interface and supports many different Events and Actions. Events: Countdown, On Time, Winamp Stops, Low CPU Usage, User Inactive, Battery Low, Window Closes, Process Stops, Ping Stops, File Size Limit. Actions: Shutdown, Reboot, Log Off, Lock Workstation, Sleep, Hibernate, Monitor Turn Off, Un/Mute Master Volume, Hang Up, Alarm, Play Sound, Execute Program.
>
> Desktop links can be created to execute any of the supported actions directly from desktop. Web Interface allows remote execution of actions and displays run-time information about the computer: Up Time, List of Processes, Screenshot of a Desktop, Program Execution, and more.

[image: 1]

Comment: And if you use Shutter and want to KEEP it monitoring, add a `Restart events` action in the `Utilities` category.

Answer (score 1):

Set up process termination logging. You can then have a scheduled task triggered by these events. The scheduled task can run a powershell script to examine the event and see if the image name is explorer.exe. If it does, then do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I found it looking for something similar so in case anyone else finds this, since it doesn't really have an answer

So wouldn't this just be easier to accomplish by setting a scheduled task to run every 5, 10, 30 minutes & have it set to not start a new instance if it's already running? I mean it's not instant, & the task scheduler will be running a check every few minutes, but that's the same thing as any 3rd Party App would be doing but lighter, & requires less resources than creating a log, opening a program to read the log, & essentially searching the log for a specific entry all the time. It's not perfect, but it's better than any of the previous suggestions